# int to string, string index number error

Tags: c#

Hey I want to turn my six digit int into a string. My current code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Euler_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string snum;
            int num;
            string final = "nul";
            char first;
            char second;
            for (int i = 100, h = 100; i < 999; i++, h++)
            {
                num = i * h;
                snum = num.ToString();
                first = snum[0];
                second = snum.ToCharArray()[5]; //Line of interest
                if (first == second)
                {
                    final = snum;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(final);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it keeps returning a index out of range exception when I try to run it.  If it starts at 0 then wouldn't the sixth digit be [5] and [4] returns the fifth digit so I'm at a loss here.

Comment: You don't need `ToCharArray`. The indexer of `string` will do the job already.

Comment: Why don't you just use `ToString()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
100 * 100 = 10000
            01234 <- array indexes.
```

There are only *five* digits in `10000`, see above. The indexes range from 0 thru 4 inclusive so trying to extract index 5 is going to cause you grief.

If you want to check the first and last digits for equality, the first can be obtained with a simple loop and the last can be found with the modulo operator:

```
int firstDigit = num;
while (firstDigit / 10 > 0) firstDigit /= 10;
int lastDigit = num % 10;
```

That way you can compare them without the relatively expensive operation of turning them into strings first (trust me, that's not something you want to be doing for Euler problems).

You can even optimise that loop since you know all the candidate numbers are either five or six digits:

```
int firstDigit;
if (num < 100000) firstDigit = num /  10000;
else              firstDigit = num / 100000;
int lastDigit = num % 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Num will be 5 digits for the first iteration since 100*100 == 10000 which is stored as a string of length 5. Since arrays are 0 indexed your string can only be indexed 0-4

[5] will be out of bounds since that would assume a string of length 6

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 100, h = 100; i < 999; i++, h++)
    {
        num = i * h;
        snum = num.ToString();
        first = snum.ToCharArray()[0];
        second = snum.ToCharArray()[4];
        if (snum.ToCharArray().Length > 5)
        {
            second = snum.ToCharArray()[5]; //Line of interest
        }
        if (first == second)
        {
            final = snum;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The length of the snum should be check before assigning in first and second.......